# CheckedListBox: How to increase size of checkbox and change color of tick mark

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, checkedlistbox

I want to override default look of **CheckedListBox** as below:
[image: Large checkbox in listbox]

**Please Note the increased size of checkbox and colored tick mark.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to create own custom control by inheriting CheckedListbox and need to override `OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)` event

> Below is the Code :

```
class BigCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    public BigCheckedListBox()
    {
        ForeColor = Color.Turquoise;
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12f);
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        var b = e.Bounds;
        var state = GetItemChecked(e.Index) ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
        Size glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, state);
        int checkPad = (b.Height - glyphSize.Height) / 2;
        var pt = new Point(b.X + checkPad, b.Y + checkPad);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(pt, new Size(20, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, rect);//This is for Checkbox rectangle

        //This is for drawing string text
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), Font, brush, pt.X + 27f, pt.Y); 


        if (state == CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            using (Font wing = new Font("Wingdings", 17f, FontStyle.Bold))
                e.Graphics.DrawString("ü", wing, brush, pt.X-4, pt.Y-1); //This is For tick mark
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will serve the purpose.